# How to equate the list elements to values list in a compact way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, associations

Consider some list of keys

```
keys={"1","2","3","4"}
```

and the list of values

```
vals={1,2,3,4};
```

I wanted to equate them as

```
quantity[#]&/@keys=vals
```

but I get an error

> Set::write: Tag Map in (quantity[#1]&)/@{1,2,3,4} is Protected

If setting `Evaluate[quantity[#]&/@keys]=vals`, it makes `quantity[key]` unusable after next launches. How to equate the values to keys in the compact way?

.

Comment: What do you mean by "equate"? You want to test whether they are [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) or you want to set the values of `quantity`? Also, what do you mean by "it makes `quantity[key]` unusable after next launches"?

Comment: @Domen : I want to set the values, and the call them by `quantity[key]`. If using `Evaluate`, I do not get the value for `quantity` in a proper way.

Comment: `Clear[quantity]; keys = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; vals = {1, 2, 3, 4}; Evaluate[quantity[#] & /@ keys] = vals; quantity["1"]` returns `1`. Why is this not the correct result?

Comment: @Domen : If you try to evaluate this code the second time (without `Clear[quantity]`), then it will say something like `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.`. And then `quantity` will become unusable. Since I will assign values of `quantity` to different keys, clearing it would be a risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html).

```
keys = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4};

MapThread[(quantity[#1] = #2) &, {keys, vals}]
```